# safest way to cypher an user id on php

Tags: php, security

I need to append an user id to a public url, I'm not a security expert and I need to know the best way to secure it.
I thougt that cypher the id and the append it to the url, and decypher it on the function called by the url, but I need to be the only one thant can decypher it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Unless your app has other security problems, exposing a user id shouldn't be a security issue.

Comment: If you really need to, use a very very lightweight cipher. Not sure why you would need to cypher their ID but if you do use a lightweight one, unless there's a huge security flaw as to why you need to obscure it

Comment: It's long to explain,but I need the id to log the user without the password,this is the reason beacuse I need to cyper the ID

Comment: Sounds like you want to create some sort of time-limited login key, which is associated with a user id in your database only - and which expires, so it can't easily be reused. But I recommend becoming a bit more of a security expert before trying to implement passwordless login.

Comment: ID's are static. They don't change so using that is a bad idea. I would go for @ChrisLear suggestion with a generated user key instead. That way, if someone suspects a key to have fallen in the wrong hands, you can always generate a new key. If you go for encrypting the ID, then it can't really be redacted and regenerated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a one-time-only or limited-time-only unique ID to give to the user (I'm guessing this is maybe in some kind of email link or something?) then you could potentially create a GUID or UUID and associate that with the user (via a database table perhaps), and have a field to mark when it's been used or expired.

A GUID/UUID is near-enough guaranteed to be unique and isn't easy to randomly guess.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is by implementing a SSO mecanism (Single Sign On).
The user will enter his password on the first app and use a secure link to access the second app.

The first app generates a public key encrypted with a private key known by the two apps.
The second app generates the public key to and if it matches the key appended to the URL then its safe to log the user.

Here an example :

The first app will create a public key :

```
$privateKey = `123azerty456`;
$publicKey = hash('sha512', 'user_id' . $privateKey);
$url = 'second_app.com/example.php?user_id=foo&key='.$publicKey;
```

The script on the second app will compute the key on its own based on the user_id passed as an argument and using the same private key :

```
$privateKey = `123azerty456`;
$checkPublicKey = hash('sha512', $_GET['user_id'] . $privateKey);

if($checkPublicKey == $_GET['key']) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'UNAUTHORIZED';
}
```

Comment: That would still require the user to login using their password in case they aren't already logged in. And if they already are logged in, you wouldn't need to pass anything at all, just link to the site.

Comment: Its not actually about signon, its more about tracking a user, I think